# TypeError when trying to get a dataframe column by a header

Tags: python, pandas

I've loaded one of the builtin datasets from sklearn into a pandas dataframe.
I would like to extract the data from a single column, as specified by that column's header.
However, this gives a type error, and I can't figure out why.
An MWE is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
meh = load_breast_cancer()

X = pd.DataFrame(meh.data, columns=[meh.feature_names])

# Prints nice dataframe
print(X)  

# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
print(X["mean radius"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you created `MultiIndex` with pass nested lists, so is necessary remove `[]` only:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(meh.data, columns=meh.feature_names)

print(X.columns)
Index(['mean radius', 'mean texture', 'mean perimeter', 'mean area',
       'mean smoothness', 'mean compactness', 'mean concavity',
       'mean concave points', 'mean symmetry', 'mean fractal dimension',
       'radius error', 'texture error', 'perimeter error', 'area error',
       'smoothness error', 'compactness error', 'concavity error',
       'concave points error', 'symmetry error', 'fractal dimension error',
       'worst radius', 'worst texture', 'worst perimeter', 'worst area',
       'worst smoothness', 'worst compactness', 'worst concavity',
       'worst concave points', 'worst symmetry', 'worst fractal dimension'],
      dtype='object')
```

**Details**:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(meh.data, columns=[meh.feature_names])
print(X.columns)

MultiIndex([(            'mean radius',),
            (           'mean texture',),
            (         'mean perimeter',),
            (              'mean area',),
            (        'mean smoothness',),
            (       'mean compactness',),
            (         'mean concavity',),
            (    'mean concave points',),
            (          'mean symmetry',),
            ( 'mean fractal dimension',),
            (           'radius error',),
            (          'texture error',),
            (        'perimeter error',),
            (             'area error',),
            (       'smoothness error',),
            (      'compactness error',),
            (        'concavity error',),
            (   'concave points error',),
            (         'symmetry error',),
            ('fractal dimension error',),
            (           'worst radius',),
            (          'worst texture',),
            (        'worst perimeter',),
            (             'worst area',),
            (       'worst smoothness',),
            (      'worst compactness',),
            (        'worst concavity',),
            (   'worst concave points',),
            (         'worst symmetry',),
            ('worst fractal dimension',)],
           )
```

Comment: @ahura - It is `'broken MultiIndex'`, because no second value. Btw, really hard looking problem ;(